# Unable to use a installed Python package

Tags: python, pypi

I used `pip install aesthetic-ascii` to install an ASCII image creator for my Python 3, but when I run the code, it gives me this:

`Traceback (most recent call last): File "c:/Users/(USER)/Programming/PY 3/Programs/Aesthetic ascii testing.py", line 1, in <module> from aesthetic_ascii import synthesize ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'aesthetic_ascii'`

code:

```
# initialize drive object (to generate visuals)
drive = synthesize.Drive()
# generate a ASCII visual (dark_mode optional)
drive.generate(dark_mode=True)
# save to png
drive.to_png('aesthetic.png')
```

the program is from https://pypi.org/project/aesthetic-ascii/

Comment: often happens when you have multiple installs of python in your machine

Comment: Use in top `from aesthetic_ascii import synthesize` in your code

Comment: @toRex yes I do have `from aesthetic_ascii import synthesize` in the code

Answer (score 0):

Which version of python are you running the code? If you have both, `python2` and `python3` installted, the pip for `python3` is called `pip3`. Try this:

```
pip3 install aesthetic-ascii
```

If you are not sure about which pip to use, you can call pip with the python version you are using:

```
python3 -m pip instal aesthetic-ascii
```

Comment: It still gives me the error that the module is not found
I'm using VSC for Py3
Although I used the terminal in VSC to download the module it doesn't work.

Comment: Make sure that you use the same interpreter run in the terminal as for the execution of your program in VSC. Have you tried to run the code manually from the terminal?

Comment: What do you mean by interpreter? And yes I've tried to run the code manually from the terminal. Uninstalling then installing the package didn't work either.